# How to add an icon (flair) to a CalendarEvent?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

I'm using Google Apps Script to create/edit some [CalendarEvents](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-event).

How can I add an icon to the event?

I know I can manually add flairs using [Event Flairs gadget](http://eventflairs.appspot.com/). But how can I add them using Google Apps Script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [the Advanced Calendar Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/calendar), this is possible. 
Create a Google Apps Script-file, and [enable the advanced calendar service.](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced)

Then create a function like this one:

```
function createEventWithFlair() {
var calendarId = "Enter calendarID here" 
var title = "Enter a title here"
var location = "Enter a location here"
var description = "Enter a description <b>here</b>" // simple html (<a><b>) is allowed
var startTime = "Sat May 26 23:59:59 GMT+02:00 2017" // must be an ISO-string ==> var date = new Date().toISOString();
var endTime = "Sun May 27 23:59:59 GMT+02:00 2017"

var gadget = {}
    gadget.display = "chip"   //Change to "icon" if you only want an icon to appear in the Google Calendar
    gadget.iconLink = "https://gamesrfunny.weebly.com/uploads/9/5/5/8/9558194/bird-blue.ico" //Link to ico-file.
    gadget.height = 20 
    gadget.width = 20
    gadget.type = 'image/ico'

var event = {
    summary: title,
    location: location,
    description:description,
    start: {
      dateTime: startTime
    },
    end: {
      dateTime: endTime
    },
    attendees: guests,
    // Red background. Use Calendar.Colors.get() for the full list.
    colorId: 11,
    gadget: gadget,

  };


var event = Calendar.Events.insert(event, calendarId);
Logger.log(event.htmlLink)
}
```

The full list of properties can be read in the [resource representation](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events) page.

Answer (score 1):

Google Calendar doesn't provide native support for event icons, so neither does the API or Apps Script.

Comment: Now I'm just curious, how do Event Flairs work? How does it manage to attach icons to events?